# Python merge multiple excel worksheets into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with 10 worksheets. Some worksheets have data and some are empty, but this changes regularly, which includes the first and/or last worksheets.

Using Python 2.7, what i am doing is load all of the worksheets into a pandas df to process in another function. I also am adding a column with the worksheet name. loading the worksheets seems to be working fine, but one of my columns has values 14-20 characters long ending in 0's. so when i print out the dict, they look correct, but pandas is converting to sci notation and i can not figure out how to keep these values.

here is some dict data:

```
           API_NUM        NAME         DATE_START DATE_FINISH  SH_NAME
0   12345678910000   RAYES A - 1       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Andy
1   12345678900000   RAYES A - 2       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Mine
2   23456789090000   RAYES A - 3       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Shef
3   34567890600000   RAYES A - 4       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Mary
4   45678901220000   RAYES A - 5       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Tom
```

so when i read in the data like below it loads fine

```
excel_file ='my path to a xlsx'
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=None)
full_table = pd.DataFrame()
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet['SH_NAME'] = name
    sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
    full_table = full_table.append(sheet)
full_table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

printing

```
sheets_dict
```

the API_NUM appears like it should, but full_table scientific notates the number.

But    -*this ended up working after all*-

```
full_table['API_NUM'] = full_table['API_NUM'].map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))


           API_NUM        NAME         DATE_START DATE_FINISH  SH_NAME
0        1234567891    RAYES A - 1       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Andy
1        123456789     RAYES A - 2       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Mine
2        2345678909    RAYES A - 3       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Shef
3        3456789060    RAYES A - 4       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Mary
4        4567890122    RAYES A - 5       2018-07-28  2018-08-25   Tom
```

---

---

---

when i convert the values to strings, they become something like -2147483648

writing the df out to a csv, the column has the trailing 0's dropped.

The issue is, later in a different function, i create a string list of these values to do a sql query. so later on, it would look like:

```
myTableValue IN ('12345678910000', '12345678900000', '23456789090000', '34567890600000', '45678901220000')
```

and the field that i am running the query on, is a string field.

---

---

---

Edited:
     I believe the lambda function ended up working after all, it was a case of bad data and myself that was giving me the problems. So that method or the one below will work. This may be helpful for someone wanting to merge worksheets into a df with Python

Comment: Is the scientific notation, representing a different value? Eg 100000000 expressed as 1e8 is the same value. Otherwise consider storing the API Num as an integer rather than floating point number.

Comment: I am just trying to get the actual values, not the sci notation, which i get as an integer

Answer (score 1):

Well, to solve my own post. What seems to have worked was a different approach for loading the worksheets.Now i'm sure one of you gurus will know why this worked and the above method did not, but this way is simpler anyways for anyone that would like to use it.

```
import xlrd

excel = 'path to my file'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(excel)


# get a list of work sheet names
sheetlist = []
for sheet in book.sheet_names():
    sheetlist.append(sheet)

# create and ordered dict of the worksheets
dfs = pd.read_excel(excel, sheetname=sheetlist)

df = pd.concat((df.assign(source=sheet) for sheet, df in dfs.items()), ignore_index=True)
df['API_NUM'] = df['API_NUM'].astype(str)
```